# Causal Impact confidence interval and statistical significance

Tags: causalimpact

I am analyzing effect of a regional marketing campaign using the causal impact R package.

I am getting posterior tail-area probability p: 0.02951, which I understand should be a significant result.

However, the 95% CI still includes zero: [-356.6, 15435]

This is strange, since I would assume that if the result is significant, the CI should not include zero.

Or do I understand something wrong?

Comment: "Posterior" implies a Bayesian approach, while a confidence interval (different from a credible interval) is a frequentist method. Bayesian and frequentist approaches need not agree.

Comment: Additionally, your "posterior tail area" may be one-tailed, so it is only telling how big the far right or far left tail is. This means we would need to double to p-value to allign with a 95% C.I., gibing you a p-value of .058, which seems more in line with your ci.